# Where can I acquire Succubi/Liliths?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

Where is a good place to farm [Succubus](http://www.puzzledragonx.com/en/monster.asp?n=96) (or higher variants, but Succubus is presumably the easiest)?

I had decent luck farming Nagas from Hyperion Lava Flow - Serpent Loved by Flame, but I've spent a couple hundred stamina running the dark equivalent, Clayus Prison - Witch of the Darkness, and gotten no Succubi to show for it.

Where would I have the best drop chance to stamina ratio for acquiring Succubus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sky Dragon's Domain - Twilight in the Sky and Legendary Dragons' Footprints - Abyss both have very high drop rates for Succubus. These dungeons both take 30 stamina to enter, but you'll probably get a Succubus within your 3rd or 4th try. However, these dungeons are only unlocked after Ocean of Heaven (if I'm not mistaken?) and so you may need to advance more. Other than that, Satan's descended has a moderate drop rate for Succubus.

Comment: Good call on Legendary Dragons & Sky Dragons, since those have 2x drop chance on weekends.